# Error when attaching files with PhoneGap EMailComposer plugin

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, email-attachments

I'm using Phonegap [EMailComposer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer) plugin with Android to send a file attached but when the mail client (gmail app) opens I always get the same error "the file can't be attached'.

This is the code I'm using:

```
cordova.plugins.email.open({    
                        to: 'XX',
                        subject: 'XX',
                        body:    'XX',
                        attachments: '//file.csv'
                    });
```

I'm quite sure the path is right becasuse when I use any other file path the error changes into "attached file can't be empty'.

I'm using cordova CLI 4.0.0 and plugin version is 0.8.2. I've tested it in Android 4.4.2 and 4.2.1

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you need to use

```
 attachments: 'file:///storage/sdcard/icon.png', //=> Android
```

but that didn't work for me so I tried without `storage` and it works for me. (I'm using Android 5.1.1 for my tests, so i don't know if it works in your case for Android 4.x)

Try with:

```
attachments: 'file:///sdcard/file.csv
```